# Странное поведение при отладке программы, работающей с Teradata

Tags: c#, .net, отладка, teradata

В программе для подключения к `Teradata` используется `Teradata.Client.Provider`. 
Вот код для подключения к хранилищу:

```
TdConnectionStringBuilder csb_td = new TdConnectionStringBuilder();
csb_td.UserId = "user";
csb_td.Password = "password";
csb_td.DataSource = "teradata";
csb_td.SessionCharacterSet = "UTF8";

x = new TdConnection(csb_td.ToString());
x.Open();
```

Если поставить точку останова перед строкой `x.Open()`, то при проходе через эту строку программа "думает" порядка 30 секунд, затем выдается исключение

> [.NET Data Provider for Teradata] [100002] Cannot create connection
>   within the time specified.

Если метод `Open` не выполнять в режиме трассировки, то он отрабатывает быстро и без исключений. Как можно объяснить такое поведение? Почему возникает таймаут соединения при трассировке?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что в режиме трассировки вы собираете приложение для отладки (Debug), а при обычном запуске приложение создано с конфигурацией Release. Проверьте, соответствуют ли конфигурационные файлы для Release и Debug. Возможно в Debug конфиге не описан .NET Data Provider for Teradata

Comment: В обычном запуске я запускаю ту же Debug-сборку. Использую SharpDevelop 4.4.